# Integer proof equivalence class

Tags: number-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I've been searching online but I couldn't find help on this matter.
How can I prove that $[(a,b)]+[(c,d)]=[(a+c,b+d)]$ is independent of the choice I make of representatives of the equivalence classes?
Thanks!

Comment: What equivalence relation are you working with?

Comment: The same as it appears in wikipedia. (a,b)~(c,d) iff a+d=b+c

Comment: Is it the construction of the integers as pairs of natural numbers by any chance?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Yes, I've already been able to prove this but now I need to demonstraste what I've asked

Comment: Yeah sorry, it,s fixed now. Let me check your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with the assumption
$$
(a, b) \sim (a', b'), \quad (c, d) \sim (c', d'),
$$
and you have to prove
$$
(a + c, b + d) \sim (a' + c', b' + d').
$$
Just appeal to the definition of $\sim$. It is  just a matter of some simple calculations then.

Comment: Thanks! Perfectly demonstrated

Comment: @CristianEduardoLehuedeLyon, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$\rm\begin{eqnarray} {\bf Hint}\qquad\quad\ \ \ 
\rm (A,B) \sim (a,b) &\iff&\rm A+b\, =\, a+B\\
\rm (C,D) \sim (c,d) &\iff&\rm C+d\, =\, c+D\\
\rm(A\!+\!C,B\!+\!D)\sim (a\!+\!c,b\!+\!d)&\iff&\rm A\!+\!C\!+\!b\!+\!d\, =\, a\!+\!c\!+\!B\!+\!D
\end{eqnarray}$

The definition of addition does not depend on choice of class rep's if the first two rhs equations imply the third rhs equation. That inference is, hopefully, clear from the above.